# Is making tawbah sufficient for lying when swearing on the Quran?

Tags: quran, tawba, oaths, lying

I swore on the Quran while lying and I'm very regretful of my sin, very.  I can not fast 3 days or feed 10 people. Or pay the fee of committing this sin (reasons).

I made tawbah and prayed and made more tawbah. Am I still forgiven?

Comment: I don't think it is even allowed to swear on the Quran. A muslim can only swear by Allah.

Comment: @TheZ you’re absolutely correct. No one can swear on anyone or anything beside God. The Prophet said, “if you do not want to swear on God, then be silent.” Something like this I read.

Comment: Please ask these questions to people of knowledge instead of posting it on here. Find local scholars at your mosques near your house and ask them. Posting them on sites where anyone can answer may lead to falsehood.

Comment: You should give us more details: what exactly have you done and said. Note that swearing on the qur'an itself is meaningless as it is bid'ah [Is a forced oath taken by placing hand on the qur'an valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49579/is-a-forced-oath-taken-by-placing-hand-on-quran-valid/49651#49651). So what is important is what you've done and said. An oath is an oath and the kafarah is the same.

Answer (score 1):

according to islamweb.net , it's a debt that you owe until you are capable. Also , you can appoint someone to feed on your behalf

https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/159579

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue before. You are forgiven insha allah swt. swearing on the book of allah for avoiding bigger problems such as ruining a marriage, ruining relationships between people that might lead to fights and even death, etc...

Allah forgives you and pardons you, but you should not use this as a covering for swearing too much in the book of allah swt. fear allah and never do it again unless its very necessary for reasons such as those mentioned above. This is my opinion and understanding of the holy Quran. may allah forgive us all.

Comment: This is not anb answer as we expect here (see [answer]).